# Script to Pull Regex Values from Text File

Tags: regex, scripting

I have a text file that I export from a honeypot that lists any files uploaded to it for development of AV signatures. In order to develop the signatures, they must be in a specific format:

SizeofFile:MD5ofFile:NameofFile

I'm trying to script the extraction of these 3 values from the exported file to create these signatures formatted properly in a new document. My sample exported data looks like:

> File
>   [Tab] Name: Name of file.extension
>   [Tab] Size: Size of File
>   [Tab] MD5: MD5 string
>   [Tab] Information: Useless information
>   [Tab] Detailed Info: Useless information
>   [Tab] Notes: Useless Information
>   [Line Break]
>   File
>   [Tab] Name: Name of file.extension
>   [Tab] Size: Size of File
>   [Tab] MD5: MD5 string
>   [Tab] Information: Useless information
>   [Tab] Detailed Info: Useless information
>   [Tab] Notes: Useless Information

Is there a way to script the extraction of the Name, Size, and Hash for each block of text that starts with File and dump that formatted string into a new document? I have the ability to run batch scripts, Macros in Office, or anything in Notepad++.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Could you post a sample row or two and can work out the regex.

Comment: Sure! Here's how the text looks raw:  
File<br>
Name: card.exe<br>
Size: 5123<br>
MD5: A486EDD5D966FD167F9D8FA94087913E<br>
Information: Malware<br>
Detailed Information: Zeus Family<br>
Notes: Financial Malware<br>
<br>
File<br>
Name: botch.docx<br>
Size: 12543<br>
MD5: D51F45E1985DC69CC6BC2B3AE1DA48F1<br>
Information: Malware<br>
Detailed Info: Z.bot<br>
Notes: Financial Trojan<br>

Comment: You said you have the ability to run batch scripts -- what type of scripts? Like windows scripts, linux scripts, python scripts etc?

Comment: You are aware that `<br>` is not the equivalent of `[TAB]`, right? Which is it that your data contains, CR/LF pairs or TAB characters? They're not the same, and the regex will vary considerably based on what you're actually asking. Have you actually attempted to do this yourself?

Comment: I took the example literately as that is what I requested.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your comment, here's what I came up with to extract the Name, Size and MD5.

`Name: (?<filename>\w+\.\w{3})\t Size: (?<size>\d+)\t MD5: (?<md5>[\w\d]+)`

From here each field will be placed in named groups called: "filename", "size" and "md5".

Python example would be:

```
import re
 reobj = re.compile(r"Name: (?P<filename>\w+\.\w{3})\t Size: (?P<size>\d+)\t MD5: (?P<md5>[\w\d]+)", re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
 match = reobj.search(subject)
 if match:
     result = match.group("groupname")
 else:
     result = ""
```